# Should I place every class in separate file?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Should I place every class in separate file? Even those short helper classes that are used only in one place? Like this one:

```
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : GenericValueConverter<int, Visibility>
{
    protected override Visibility Convert(int value)
    {
        return value == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a class that really needs to be a separate class but is also only used in one place, it's probably best to keep it in the same file. If this is happening frequently, though, you might have a bigger problem on your hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends greatly of personal preference, but I like to do it.

In this case, I would have a folder inside my application called ValueConverters, and put all converters, including short ones, inside their own files.

I find it makes it easier to get an overview of what your project consist of from the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

I do this and it is usually best practice to do so, but it is sometimes a matter of opinion.

Comment: What a non answer. It is usually but really a matter of opinion? What?

Comment: I don't see the issue. It is usually best practice but some people don't do it, what is wrong with that?

Comment: 'Usually best practice' because some companies I have worked for don't have it as best practice and some do. 'Sometimes a matter of opinion' because some people really don't care and some do. The issue is with the question itself rather than the answer, and other people have just re-iterated what I have said. Hope this clears it up for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'll rephrase the question for you: should I use [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com)? (it includes this rule). The answer is yes. I use it and my code is much more readable (but I have to admit I disable all the rules that require the method documentation to be complete :-) )

I do think that when you program in a team, having a fixed and uniform code format is very important. And even when you program "solo". A cluttered code is more difficult to read and errors can hide better in the clutter :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is usually the best practise to put every class in a seperate file. Taking into account your short helper classes; you could create a helper class which contain all your helper methods, to prevent having way too many classes. If your helper class gets too big, you can seperate your helper functions per category

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to do so.

You can easily find the class if you name the file after the class.

Resharper has a built in error for classes not matching the file name they are in...

Comment: Why would I search for the class that is used only in one place and is declared in the same file?

Comment: @Poma - Today, only in one place. And tomorrow? You will write a new one because you can't find the existing helper.

Comment: @Poma - What if you suddenly need to use it in another place in your application when it gets extended later on? Build your application with regards to extensibility instead of taking shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, IMO yes. Think about any new developers who must find where code lives. Yes, you can use go to definition, but that is not the be all, end all. However, I will say that sometimes if you have an interface that is small and only used for the class that it is within, then you can probably get away with it. However, even that can expand and later be required to be pulled out (and maybe those contracts should be in another namespace anyways).

So, ultimately, I would say the majority of the time, yes, but there are some caveats. As with anything, it is never black and white